# The banishment felt around the world

Tags: discussion, moderation, voting

...our little *Vi and Vim SE* world, that is. :P

If you're reading this there's a good chance that you know what I'm talking about. Last month a user was banned from our little slice of heaven and with him went a *sizable* amount of voting points.

Now the amount of points lost by any one individual was pretty insignificant<sup>1</sup>, I think. High-volume and/or old-timer contributors look to have lost generally 100-200 points. (-90 myself). It *is* kind of amusing to see the monthly leader board looking like it has been completely flipped as [the majority of old-timers are on the last page of results](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/599/month/vi/2019-05-01?sort=reputationchange&page=8)

Other than that it's not a particularly significant event.

**BUT**...my curiosity is getting the better of me. I'm sure someone figured out who it was. Who? Are there any details (lurid or not) publicly available? :)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Much more and I have to think some portion of the user base would start getting ticked. Seems like kind of a dicey policy to me...penalizing everyone for something that's no fault of their own. (There's a loophole where those points can be preserved at discretion of SE Staff but don't know if it's ever used.)</sub>

Comment: *There's a loophole where those points can be preserved at moderators discretion but don't know if it's ever used* To clarify, these points can be preserved at the discretion of [**an SE Employee**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328674/286591). And it's not supposed to be a "punishment" to remove the votes.

Comment: That was lazy on my part. Don't want to imply anything about our moderators here. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: As for whether it's _supposed to_ be punishment or not that's immaterial, really. All that matters is how users _actually feel_ about it, of course. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short – if unsatisfactory – answer is *"one or more users deleted their profiles, and there's really not anything further we can discuss about the topic for privacy reasons"*, [from animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328644/166789).

Adding to this, as a mod I know a wee little bit more than the general public, but not much.

Comment: It seems no one here is in the mood for idle speculation and rumor-mongering. Too bad. But the link you provided (along with some sub-links) more than satisfied my need for both and even revealed some actual, hitherto unknown to me, facts. Thanks for that. And...you win!